# How can I give the skybox a blur effect like blender?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am studying OpenGL at Learn-OpenGL.

Here I learned about skybox and framebuffer.

So I can see that I can blur the skybox by capturing it in the framebuffer.

I want to see a screen like this image:

[image: img]

But, when rendering with this framebuffer, the object is overwritten and only the skybox is visible.

this is my code:

```cpp
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, skybox_framebuffer->get_fbo());
        {
            // skybox capture
            glViewport(0, 0, skybox_framebuffer->get_width(), skybox_framebuffer->get_height());
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            skybox.draw(camera, projection);
        }
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        {
            glViewport(0, 0, g_window.get_width(), g_window.get_height());
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            skybox_framebuffer->draw();
            draw_model(ourModel, ourShader, view, projection);
        }
```

Even changing the drawing order gave the same result:

[image: img].

And, if I draw the SKYBOX directly instead of the framebuffer, I get this result:

[image: img].

### Solution1

I think the solution is to use the stencil buffer.

my solution code:

```cpp
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        {
            glViewport(0, 0, g_window.get_width(), g_window.get_height());
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
            glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

            // draw model
            glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
            glStencilMask(0xFF);
            draw_model(ourModel, ourShader, view, projection);

            // draw skybox framebuffer
            glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
            glStencilMask(0x00); // disable writing to the stencil buffer
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            skybox_framebuffer->draw();

            glStencilMask(0xFF);
            glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }
```

and my solution result:

[image]

### Solution2

using `glDepthMask`

This shows the same screen as solution1 without the stencil buffer.

```cpp
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        {
            glViewport(0, 0, g_window.get_width(), g_window.get_height());
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
            skybox_framebuffer->draw();
            glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
            draw_model(ourModel, ourShader, view, projection);
        }
```

### question

I could implement it like this,

Is there any way to blur the skybox without using the framebuffer, other than using a blurred image?

Comment: too lazy to inspect your code but the results look like you store the frames before you render your objects ... Also why are you `glClear` ing twice?

Comment: @Spektre I understand that `glClear` is done for each framebuffer. So I called it twice.

Comment: no You should clear only the rendering framebuffer depth, blend in the last frame with new skybox and store result for next frame and then render your objects (no clearing of color at all) ... if you want to blur also objects then you just store the frame after rendering them ... If you want also preserve depth then do not even clear depth ... but then you have to convert the depths to new coordinate system (pose) and fill in the gaps... The only time where you use glClear is when you create the framebuffer on app init or resize event or change of scene ...

Comment: also for motion blur is better to have more consequent frames (like 3..5) not just one

Comment: Are you perhaps using depth testing wrong? The skybox should be rendered with a greater depth than the character model, or alternatively you should render it first with depth testing and depth write disabled. Stencil shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Andrea `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);` is work! No more stencil buffers!. But is there a way to not use the framebuffer to give the blur effect? Or is it best to use a blurred image as a texture?

Comment: @Nor-s Blurring is a "post-processing effect" that is typically done with framebuffers.